# W3C Validater error "Duplicate attribute id."

Tags: html

![What is the difference between Duplicate ID and Duplicate attribute ID.
and how to solved Duplicate attribute ID issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkXBC.png)

Comment: Please explain your question clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Duplicate attribute id.” means that you have defined the `id` twice.

For example

```
<div id="1232" attr1=""  id="...">
```

remove on of the id attributes and the error should gone.

"Duplicate id" means you have two tags with the same id.

For example

```
 <div id="1"></div>
 <div id="1"></div>
```

rename the id of one element.

Answer (score 0):

You used the same ID on line 340 and 352, so you have the duplicate id error. It isn't clear from your screenshot but I think you are using the id attribute twice inside one tag

https://validator.w3.org/docs/errors.html